# Using many monitors (4+) in linux

Tags: xorg, drivers, monitors

I want to be able to run more than 4 monitors (maybe 6) and it's extremely confusing what's compatible now with the Displayport cards coming out. Right now I have an ATI card that only has 2 HDMI outputs. The problem I've seen is that the ATI driver says it doesn't support more than 4 monitors. So it seems that their eyefinity cards would probably be more hassle than it's worth.

I prefer nvidia anyway, they always seem to have really good linux drivers. But I don't see that they offer a card with more than 4 ports. Most of the higher end cards that I've seen have 2 hdmi, 1 dvi, and 1 displayport. Am I mistaken that those cards are limited to 4 monitors?

And what about drivers? If I get dual nvidia cards and hook up say 2 HDMI ports + the DVI port on each card, will xorg/nvidia drivers play nice? Will I be able to set up monitors with different resolutions? (I have 2 1920x1080 and 1920x1200 screens right now)?

How about x windows? Can you set up xinerama for 6 screens? Or make it able to drag x windows?

**Update**:
It seems that ati drivers have come a long way recently and that there is official eyefinity support for linux. I think I'm goin gto pick up an ATI 5870 and just see where I can get messing with it.

**Update2**:
I ordered a 5870, I'll let you guys know how it goes. I only have a couple monitors I can play with at the moment though.

Comment: Did you get something built? I've played with three displays once, but it lacked HW acceleration.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of forgot about this question. I got my 5870. The drivers worked fine. I could run 2 monitors (dp to HDMI) just fine, no problems. 3 monitors (all using dp to HDMI) didn't work (as expected). I have yet to acquire any display port monitors though. I'm fairly certain it will work though

Answer (score 10):

> How about x windows? Can you set up
>   xinerama for 6 screens? Or make it
>   able to drag x windows?

The current Xorg limit is 16 display devices, but a multi-head card will typically be treated as a single device unless you want separate logical displays (not Xinerama-style).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get Debian 6 working with 3x gfx cards and 6 screens. 
However, no 3D support with xinerama.

My xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.59  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03.nvidia.com)  Wed Jun  6 22:23:02 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Below "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" Below "Screen2"
    Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen2"
    Screen      5  "Screen5" Below "Screen4"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor5"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMB2330H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device5"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 550 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen5"
    Device         "Device5"
    Monitor        "Monitor5"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```